# Nagios has stopped sending notifications

Tags: linux, ubuntu, email, monitoring, nagios

Our Nagios server has stopped sending email notifications. If I run the notify-by-host or notify-by-service commands directly, I get email, and everything works as I expect.

When a notification is triggered, or if I trigger a custom notification, I can see the host notifications coming up in nagios.log, but nothing is showing up in mail.log and I receive no emails.

Everything was working fine a couple weeks ago.

Comment: Has anything been recently modified in your contacts.cfg or templates.cfg file?

Comment: Nope, templates/contacts.cfg hasn't been changed, looks correct and I see the notify-by-host command in the nagios.log is trying to send to the right people, but it never makes it frm Nagios to Postfix to send the email.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try running the commands from nagios user for debug

Comment: Running the command as the nagios user does give and error...I am getting permission denied from /usr/bin/mailx trying to write an email to /tmp

Comment: I/someone/something must have changed the permissions on /tmp. Changing permissions on /tmp fixed the problem and we're seeing emails now. Thanks.